# Tell WolframAlpha what variables I use

Tags: wolframalpha

When you write something like "X1 + Wa + Wb + L + Ra" Wolfram will say "Assuming
"L" is a unit [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X1%20%2B%20Wa%20%2B%20Wb%20%2B%20L%20%2B%20Ra)

Can I write something to tell Wolfram that X1,Wb,Wa,L,Ra are variables?

For example on matlab I can write "syms X1 Wb Wa L Ra"

Answer (score 3):

I can get Wolfram|Alpha to accept L...however, I cannot get it to take variables with multiple letters in the name. It assumes that any adjacent letters refer to multiplication, rather than a variable with several letters in its name.

You can just only single letter variable names: `find x + a + b + L + R for x=1, a=2, b=3, L=4, R=5`: see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+x+%2B+a+%2B+b+%2B+L+%2B+R+for+x%3D1%2C+a%3D2%2C+b%3D3%2C+L%3D4%2C+R%3D5).

You can also use `X_1` instead of just `X`, however you cannot use `Wa` or `W_a`. You can also use greek letter names, such as `alpha`.